# How do I split a string if there is a positive lookahead and a positive lookbehind but not a delimiter?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, split

Example:

```
s = "Thisissometext andthisissometext"
```

I want to split the text between "is" and "some":

```
["Thisis", "sometext andthisis", "sometext"]
```

If I do this:

```
re.split("(?<=is)s(?=ome)", s)
-->    ['Thisis', 'ometext andthisis', 'ometext']
```

no 's'

If i do this

```
re.split("(?<=is)(s)(?=ome)", s)
-->   ['Thisis', 's', 'ometext andthisis', 's', 'ometext']
```

If i do this

```
re.split("(?<=is)(?=some)", s)
-->   ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
```

How can I split a string if there is no delimiter??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which supports empty splits:

```
import regex as re

s = "Thisissometext andthisissometext"

print(re.split(r"(?V1)(?<=is)(?=some)", s))
# ['Thisis', 'sometext andthisis', 'sometext']
```

Note the `(?V1)` here which enables the newer behaviour. This can be set via a flag as well:

```
print(re.split(r"(?<=is)(?=some)", s, flags = re.VERSION1))
```

Comment: Hoi Jan, Great solution! Never heard of '(?V1)' Wow.

Comment: @Reman: Glad to help. Have provided another alternative in the bottom of the answer.

Comment: On split, I want only y in this: re.split("(?<=x)y(?=z)", text). How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple and faster approach, which works if you know a non existing character in the text, `'@'` here:

```
s.replace('issome','is@some').split('@')
# ['Thisis', 'sometext andthisis', 'sometext']
```

tests :

```
In [300]: %timeit s.replace('issome','is@some').split('@')
976 ns ± 21.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [301]: %timeit regex.split(r"(?V1)(?<=is)(?=some)", s)
7.36 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [302]: %timeit re.findall(r'[\w\s]+?(?:is(?=some)|$)', s)
4.28 µs ± 97.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Very nice but sometimes I need regex to split my string.

Comment: Plus one for the timit!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `split`, here is a regex that you can use in `re.findall` to get your job done:

```
>>> s = "Thisissometext andthisissometext"
>>> print re.findall(r'[\w\s]+?(?:is(?=some)|$)', s)
['Thisis', 'sometext andthisis', 'sometext']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OsjRVc/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[\w\s]+?`: Match 1+ word or space characters (**non-greedy**)
- `(?:`: Start a non-capturing group

  - `is`: Match literal `is`
  - `(?=some)`: That must be followed by `some`
  - `|`: OR
  - `$`: it is end of string
- `)`: End non-capturing group